# Add hyphen to query results

Tags: php, mysql

I need to add an hyphen to the results of my query. I need to do this so it's easier to  put the values in excel som you can make a graph of it.

Query:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(Orderdatum),MONTH(Orderdatum)) AS Orderdatum,Artikelnr,OrderKund, 
SUM(Forspris) as Forspris,SUM(Levereratantal) as Levereratantal FROM orderhuvud left JOIN orderrad on orderhuvud.Ordernummer = orderrad.Ordernummer
 where ". $query ." GROUP BY CONCAT(YEAR(Orderdatum),(MONTH(Orderdatum)) + 0,Artikelnr"
```

Query result:

```
Orderdatum    Artikelnr   levereratantal
20154         82052076        15
20154         82135156        8
20154         82328298        55
20154         82474306        8
20154         82812838        20
```

The results that i need:

```
Orderdatum    Artikelnr   levereratantal
2015-4        82052076        15
2015-4        82135156        8
2015-4        82328298        55
2015-4        82474306        8
2015-4        82812838        20

Orderdatum = Order Date
Artikelnr = Article/product number
levereratantal = delivered amount
```

Comment: use: **CONCAT(YEAR(Orderdatum),'-',MONTH(Orderdatum))**

Comment: to be honest i thought it was going to be a lot harder but thanks for the answer :)

Comment: You already have a `CONCAT()` all you needed to do was read the documentation for that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweak you concat() like this way,

```
concat(YEAR(Orderdatum), '-', MONTH(Orderdatum)) AS Orderdatum
```

**OR** try with concat_ws()

```
concat_ws('-', YEAR(Orderdatum),MONTH(Orderdatum)) as Orderdatum
```